# Share persistent storage between multiple nodes in K8s using NFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nfs

I followed steps mentioned in [this](https://medium.com/swlh/quick-fix-sharing-persistent-disks-on-multiple-nodes-in-kubernetes-ef5541fd8376) blog to share persistent disk between multiple nodes.

However, still I am not able to find shared volume on nfs-server pod.

Note, I tried this on my local eks cluster. Let me know if there is something missing or is there any other better way to achieve this?

Comment: Please upload yaml of the resources you have used/created. Please upload the error messages in pod describe & pvc describe .

Comment: @confusedgenius yaml code is exactly same as mentioned in blog. There are no error as such. However, no shared volume is available on nfs-server as mentioned in blog.